Specifying $and logic in a CASL rule
I understand from the CASL docs that logic operators like $and, $or etc. have not been implemented in CASL for mongoose
$or can easily be specified by separate can rules with the same action and subject
But I don't understand quite how to implement $and. The docs only mention that

combination of cannot rules allows to mimic $not and $and operators.
Moreover as we discussed in this guide, all properties inside
conditions object are checked by AND logic, this is another way to
mimic $and operator

What exactly does that mean? I have actually no idea how to implement a rule like this correctly:
can("update", "Process", {
  userPrivileges: {
    $and: [
      { $elemMatch: { userid: user._id } },
      { $elemMatch: { canWrite: true } },
    ],
  },
});

mainly because the top level property names are the same $elemMatch, so I won't be able to combine them into one conditions object

If you need an exact element with both properties matched on  a single item in array then you can replace this with single $elemMatch which contains both props in single object. { $elemMatch: { userid:…, canWrite: true } }

If you need either case, then you can replace elemMatch with nested properties check: { ‘userPrivileges.userid’: …, ‘userPrivileges.canWrite': true }
